# Takeaway bonanza

Tags: riddle, word

> Take away 1, I am even.
> Take away 2, I am 22.
> Take away 3, I am the seasons.
> Who am I? Who may I be?

**First sentence hint:**

> Think *outside* the box. Math isn't the only solution.

**Second sentence hint:**

> 1a, 2b, 3c...

**Third sentence hint:**

> *Next time on random cooking show:* Let's **season our steak**!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are:

> 7

*Take away 1, I am even.*

> 7 minus 1 is 6, an even number. Also (as pointed out by the OP in comments), 'SEVEN' minus one letter (the 'S') makes the word 'EVEN', quite literally.

*Take away 2, I am 22.*

> 7 minus 2 is 5, which is 'V' in Roman numerals - the 22nd letter of the alphabet.

*Take away 3, I am the seasons.*

> 7 minus 3 is 4 - the number of seasons in a year (winter, spring, summer, autumn).

Comment: Perfecto! Only minor thing is, I said even because if you take the first letter away from seven, it becomes the word *even*. It's fine though, Bravo!

Comment: @WhipStreak23 Ah, I see - I used this method because it retained the same meaning of 'take away' throughout, but obviously both work fine there :)